# How to set an exception in laravel

Tags: laravel

I made a global helper function to avoid typos for database statuses

```
function status($status){

    $SUCCESS = 'SUCCESS';
    $ABORTED = 'ABORTED';
    $PENDING = 'PENDING';
    $EXPIRED = 'EXPIRED';

    $status = strtoupper($status);

    if($status === 'S'){
        return $SUCCESS;
    }
    elseif($status === 'A'){
        return $ABORTED;
    }
    elseif($status === 'P'){
        return $PENDING;
    }
    elseif($status === 'E'){
        return $EXPIRED;
    }

}
```

However, I want the code to scream at me every time I input an incorrect parameter in debug mode. how can I do that?

Comment: first, it's unclear what you really want. 2nd, these `$SUCCESS` local vars are of no real use. perhaps consts would make more sense, but if that's only for that `status()` then still useless. 3rd, array map would be probably cleaner unless you like if/else spaghetti

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just throw the exception when no situation is valid

```
function status($status){

    $SUCCESS = 'SUCCESS';
    $ABORTED = 'ABORTED';
    $PENDING = 'PENDING';
    $EXPIRED = 'EXPIRED';

    $status = strtoupper($status);

    if($status === 'S'){
        return $SUCCESS;
    }
    elseif($status === 'A'){
        return $ABORTED;
    }
    elseif($status === 'P'){
        return $PENDING;
    }
    elseif($status === 'E'){
        return $EXPIRED;
    }
    throw new \Exception('invalid status');
}
```

I would suggest you change your code to

```
function status($status){
    switch(strtoupper($status)) {
        case 'S':
            return 'SUCCESS';
        case 'A':
            return 'ABORTED';
        case 'P':
            return 'PENDING';
        case 'E':
            return 'EXPIRED';
        default:
            throw new \Exception('invalid status');
    }   
}
```